# Plot the line in the plane z=3 that makes an angle of $\pi/6$ radians with $\hat{i}$ and an angle of $\pi/3$ radians with $\hat{j}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors, visualization, angle

I'm not sure how we measure the angle between i-hat and the line and j-hat and the line. i-hat and j-hat are perpendicular to each other They are axis, x and y axis respectively.  Therefore, I don't know how to draw the line with the desired properties. By line in the plane does that mean that the line we want to draw is parallel or intersecting the plane z=3 at one point?

I'm requesting a drawing in space.

Comment: Could you draw a line that makes an angle $\pi/6$ with the x axis and an angle $\pi/3$ with the y axis in the two-dimensional case? If you do so and then add a z axis, you have done the problem in the $z=0$ plane.

Comment: so assuming xy -plane is a flat sheet of paper sitting on the desk. after I construct the line that makes ..... angles, I then lift the line up to z=3 vertically up and then i've done the problem in 3d?

Comment: Yep, keeping the line flat (parallel to the table)

Comment: It's flat and lifted?

Comment: If the table is the x y plane it is parallel to the table and above it

Comment: A line has two points. I'm sure that the line goes through ($\sqrt{3}$,1,3), what other point does this line go through?

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen

Comment: Parallel to the x-y plane. The natural choice for the other point is $(0,0,3)$

Comment: I can draw the line on the xy-plane. I draw a line with y-intercept y= 1 and x-intercept of x=$\sqrt{3}$. Now we have a line making 30 degrees with i and 60 degrees with j. This line that I draw clearly has a negative slope and does not go through the origin. I then left this thing up in the z direction by 3 units. I believe that what I have just described is the line we're talking about. I don't understand how (0,0,3) is a point on the line by my construction.

Comment: I don't know how you know that our line goes through the origin

Comment: When we say a "line in the plane" do we mean a line that is parallel to the plane or at least shares one point in common with the plane?

Comment: By line in the plane, we mean a line that is entirely in the plane, i.e. every point on the line is a point on the plane. The line you describe does not meet the criteria for the angle and the point you mentioned $(\sqrt{3},1,3)$ is not on it. It makes an angle of $5\pi/6$ with $\hat i$ and $\pi/3$ with $\hat j$.The line between $(\sqrt{3},1,3)$ and $(0,0,3)$ does meet the criteria.  I actually agree that the problem does not uniquely specify a line and it doesn't need to go through the origin (or $z$ axis, anyway). So the line between $(\sqrt{3},2,3)$ and $(0,1,3)$ would work as well.

Comment: Actually on further reflection I think that your example does meet the criteria (lines are not directed, so who am I to say whether it makes an angle of $5\pi/6$ or $\pi/6$). It remains that $(\sqrt{3},1,3)$ is not on it. But it seems by your description that you have already specified two points that are on it: $(0,1,3)$ and $(\sqrt{3},0,3),$ so that answers that question.